# Count the number of Arrays & access a specific array in the JSON Response using REST ASSURED with JAVA & Selenium

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I am doing a POST call action through my selenium Automation program using Rest Assured API & Java. IO get a response as mentioned below-

```
{
    "cmsContract": "HA1123",
    "groupId": "12345",
    "siteId": "4444-AP",
    "stateCountyCode": "7978790"
  },
  {
    "cmsContract": "HB2345",
    "groupId": "9876",
    "siteId": "8888-DK",
    "stateCountyCode": "111225"
  }
```

There are about 1000 or more JSON Objects in the response. And they don't have a identifier for the response like "name" or "contractinfo"

My query:
1. How do I retrieve the total count of the arrays (like one from '`{`' to '`}`') using Rest Assured APIs in conjuncture with JAVA and selenium?

2. If I had to retrieve '`stateCountyCode`' for the result set with '`cmsContract`' as `HB2345` , how would I do that? I would want to see the value return as  `111225`

Please suggest.

Libraries used-

```
org.json.JSONObject;
io.restassured.RestAssured;
io.restassured.response.Response;
io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Selenium... removing tags

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JsonPath` to parse JSON response. Basically, you can get `JsonPath` class from String, File or Response.

From String:

```
JsonPath path = JsonPath.from("json string");
```

From File:

```
JsonPath path = JsonPath.from(new File("path to file"));
```

From Response:

```
Response response; //we get it from RestAssured by calling POST/GET etc
JsonPath path = response.body().jsonPath();
```

In order to get any element in the JSON Structure, just like in your case, we have to provide it to `JsonPath`. Example JSON:

```
{ 
    "data": [
      {
         "name": "test"
      },
      {
         "name": "test1"
      }
    ]
}
```

In order to access an element in the Array, we have to know ALL of its parents. 
The structure looks like this:

```
path.get("parent.child.anotherChild");
```

The thing gets more tricky with Arrays because we have to use indexes.
The `"data"` in the example above is an array. In order to access `test1` we would use:

```
path.get("data[1].name"); //second element in the array
```

But that's the standard approach. JsonPath is a much stronger library.

Finally, to answer your question. How do we get a count of JSON Objects in the Array?

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> jsonObjects = path.getList("data"); //You have to provide name of the Array's parent. In my case, it's `data`
```

In the above List of HashMaps, we have ALL of JSON Objects in the JSON Array. So you can use multiple ways to count the elements.

To count how many JSON Objects there is you can simply use List's method:

```
jsonObjects.size();
```

With the same List, we can get `cmsContract` value, as in your example. We look for value `HB2345`.

Standard `for` loop. You can use Streams if you know how.

```
public String getStateCountryCodeFromCmsContract(String cmsContractValue) {
    for (HashMap<String, Object> singleJsonObject : jsonObjects) {
        String cmsContract = (String) singleJsonObject.get("cmsContract");
        if (cmsContract.equals(cmsContractValue)) {
            return (String) singleJsonObject.get("stateCountyCode");
        }
    }
}
```

We iterate over each JSON Object, check the value of `cmsContract` element, and if it equals the desired value - return `stateCountryCode` value.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So this was exactly my situation- We dont have the name to the whole set of array results like how you mentioned as 

"data": [

It just goes from

{
         "name": "test"
      },
      {
         "name": "test1"
      }

as the response from the GET/POST call.

Comment: How do I get the size of the response if I don't have anything to mention in path.getList(<>)?

Comment: @SK Let me verify that

Comment: @SK Is this full response you get? There are no other elements in JSON?

Comment: @SK What you provided is not correct JSON format. Is this all you get? Multiple JSON Objects? No root, no array?

Comment: Yes, No root. they are just arrays as response. Is there a solution in this case?

Comment: @Fenio- Sorry. That's what I meant. Only JSON Objects as response. I have spoken to the developers to update the response structure. But if this is how the response is going to be displayed, do we have a solution to access a specific JSON object (say 5th) and also to get the count of all the JSON Objects.

Comment: @SK Yes, I think we can add a little bit of manipulation. Take the JSON to String variable and modify it so it has a parent element containing array of JSON Objects.Like - your current response should be under something like `{ "data": [ current response ] }`. With the parent element we can figure out how to get to the desired element. I can show you the full solution on monday if that's ok